# How the flagging system works?

Tags: support, status-completed, flagging

If I'm not wrong, there is the possibility to raise up a maximum of 10 flags, but I don't know how the system works.

I imagine that, if I have 10 pending flag raised, I can't flag any more post, but I remember that a couple of hours ago I have seen that there was the possibility to raise up 11 flags: it was a temporary error of the system or there is the possibility to achieve more flags?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How many flags do I have?

When you start out, you are allotted **10 flags per day**. This number may increase to up to 100 flags per day:

**You get one bonus flag per 2000 reputation**.

You are awarded additional bonus flags when you flag correctly - one bonus flag for every ten net helpful flags (helpful flags minus declined flags).

https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts